# Can I Sell Software based on Itext Sharp

Tags: itext

I have a couple of small offline softwares that I wrote using Itext Sharp.  The software uses IText Sharp to manipulate PDFs. I saw that Itext licensing is AGPL and any work based on that should also be AGPL (I should include source code along with the application and user can modify and redistribute)

My question is can I sell these softwares with source codes bundled with them?

Answer (score 3):

The moment you sell software that is licensed under the AGPL in the context of proprietary, closed source software, you are in violation with the AGPL. If you use iText "free of charge", you need to follow the rules of the AGPL as described in this blog post: [How do I make sure my software complies with AGPL: How can I use iText for free?](http://itextpdf.com/blog/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free)

If you make your own source code open source, you can for instance charge for creating a distribution of your open source software (including the source of iText) on a CD or a DVD (but who still uses CDs and DVDs?), but you can't charge for the IP of iText. You also can't distribute the source code *only* to people who pay. That would be discriminating (and discrimination goes against the core values of open source).

This doesn't mean you can't make any money. The owner of the iText software, iText Group, offers two options that allow you to make money with your software:

1. You can purchase a commercial license for your use of iText. If your product is an offline product that people install on their own machine, you will have to buy a Desktop OEM license and pay a small fee for every copy you sell. Note that you need to buy an OEM pack of several licenses in advance. You can't buy OEM licenses one at a time. You need to be sure that you will sell sufficient copies.
2. You submit your products for evaluation to iText Group, and you ask iText Group to sell your product. For every copy of your software that is sold by iText Group, you will receive money. If you don't have any sales people, nor any marketing budget, this option is to be preferred. iText Group has offices in the US, Europe, and Asia. iText is present at events all over the world. This is an ideal way for you as a developer to have your product promoted world-wide. See [iText Creates Revenue Sharing Opportunities for Development Community](http://itextpdf.com/blog/itext-creates-revenue-sharing-opportunities-development-community)

See also [Monetizing open-source projects](https://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/monetizing-opensource-projects), which is a slide-deck that explains how open source licenses work, and how you can make money using open source. You will also notice some legal documents that show that the AGPL can be upheld in court (we won a law suit against a developer who knowingly violated the AGPL).